# How to move the "IN STOCK" above Add to cart button

Tags: magento2, product-view, stock, stock-status, product-detail-page

How to move the Stock availability (In Stock) next to the Quantity button.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the default theme?

Comment: No. "http://labbluesky.com/magento/eren/en6/#"

Answer (score 0):

You move that by overiding catalog_product_view.xml,

```
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. but it's coming below "add to cart". but I need above "add to cart"

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

add below code in product/view/addtocart.phtml file between qty and action button

```
<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <div class="stock available" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below code I have moved Add to cart , wishlist and instock below the short description.

The Instock will be before the add to cart

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <move element="product.info.addto" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info"/>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info"/>
    </body>
</page>
```